# How to get style in code from resource dictionary?

Tags: silverlight-3.0

If you put style in app.xmal, then you can get the style with the code like:

Style = Application.Current.Resources["myStyle"] as Style;

But if I put style in a dictionary resource of a separate file Styles.xmal like:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Then how to get the style in code?

Answer (score 8):

Found out reason: code

```
Style = Application.Current.Resources["myStyle"] as Style;
```

works fine. My problem is caused by some other factors.

Answer (score 0):

tip:

- be careful not to do `this.Resources` for the current object by mistake if what you're looking for is in Styles.xaml or Resources.xaml
- also don't expect to see all the resources in the 'add watch' dialog for `Application.Current.Resources`. ones defined in XAML won't be there (at least not on the top level)